# How to use childwindow for login page in current situation

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, silverlight-5.0, childwindow

I am silverlight beginner and under a situation where i had to Pop up a Login Page childwindow at startup (first thing must appear on launching program must be login childwindow pop up). And when password entered correctly then displaying the UI elements. (not before)

And i try to do so by Loading the childwindow in MainPage.xaml.cs and setting its visiblity to Collapsed and the idea is when user enters the correct password and username then the visiblity of UI elements(MainPage IntializeComponents();) must be visible.

I tried so like this:

```
public partial class MainPage : UserControl
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Loaded += MainPage_Loaded;

        }

       private void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            loginChildWindow log = new loginChildWindow();    
            log.Show();
        }
    }
```

and childwindow class going to pop up is:

```
public partial class loginChildWindow : ChildWindow
    {
        public loginChildWindow()
        {            
            InitializeComponent();    
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (txtUsrname.Text == "Username" && txtPassword.Password == "Password")
            {
                MainPage obj = new MainPage();
                obj.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                obj.InitializeComponent();
               this.DialogResult = true;            
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Incorrect username and/orpassword", "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK);
            }
        }
        private void CancelButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.DialogResult = false;
        }   
    }
```

The problem here is even on entering the correct informaton i set the visiblity to visible but it still do not show anything.
see this:

```
    if (txtUsrname.Text == "Username" && txtPassword.Password == "Password")
                    {
                        MainPage obj = new MainPage();
                        obj.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                        obj.InitializeComponent();
//I also tried commenting the above 3 lines and simply doing this.Visibility = Visibility.Visible; but still do not work
                       this.DialogResult = true;            
                    }
```

I think i need to set the visiblity to visible in MainPage.xaml.cs class (not in loginChildWindow.cs class) but how to know that the entered login password and username in `loginChildWindow.cs` is correct or not so that i set the visiblity to visible when the data enter is correct in MainPage.xaml.cs.

**If someone know any alternative to accomplish this problem thn please help me.**

Answer (score 0):

Finally i done the solution of thsi problem like this (for future readers) :

```
public partial class MainPage : UserControl
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Loaded += MainPage_Loaded;

        }

       private void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            loginChildWindow log = new loginChildWindow(this);
            log.Show();

        }
       public void loginWnd_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
           this.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
       }

    }
```

and:

```
 public partial class loginChildWindow : ChildWindow
    {

        private readonly MainPage _mainPage;
        public loginChildWindow(MainPage mainPage)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _mainPage = mainPage;
        }


        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (txtUsrname.Text == "Username" && txtPassword.Password == "Password")
            {

                _mainPage.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
               this.DialogResult = true;            
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Incorrect username and/orpassword", "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK);
            }
        }
        private void CancelButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.DialogResult = false;
        }   


        private void Login_Window_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
    }
```

I pass the instance of the MainPage.xaml.cs class to the loginPage class and use it there.